# How I make like this slideshow using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am trying to make a slideshow for my home page. What I need a slideshow is exactly same to this one http://www.flashmint.com/template-demo-4188.html.

This is my JavaScript -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#banner').oneByOne({
    className: 'oneByOne1',
    easeType: 'random',
    slideShow: true
  });
});
```

This is [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HLJSx/)

My problem is jquery easing effect not working in this slide show. Can anybody help me to figure this out?

Thank you.

Comment: You purchased your copy of the library, right? So you should be entitled to get help from their support people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this link http://3.s3.envato.com/files/41177958/index.html and view source code.
After that try to check in your html that is has something different from source code of that link. Maybe you have forget to include some javascript or css that important for this library.

JS and CSS that I mean

```
<script src="js/jquery.1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.onebyone.min.js"></script>              
<script src="js/jquery.touchwipe.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
 $(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#banner').oneByOne({
        className: 'oneByOne1',              
        easeType: 'random',
        slideShow: true
    });  


 });


</script> 
<link href="css/jquery.onebyone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/example1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

use this JavaScript https://github.com/madan-ram/facebook-app/blob/master/js/jslider.js and then to embed in your html code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()//$(target).(some function execution or tasks)
{
$(".slider").jslider( //$(target).(some function execution or tasks)
{
btnPrev:".next",
btnNext:".prv",
});
});
</script>
```

then in body

```
<!--start 

slider--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div id="slide_container">
<img src="./image/prev.png" class="prv"/>
<img src="./image/next.png" class="next"/>
<div class="slider">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.linux.com" ><img src="./image/linux-hardware.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.wordpress.com" ><img src="./image/wordpress.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.ubuntu.com" ><img src="./image/ubuntu.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.firefox.com" ><img src="./image/firefox-thunderbird.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://developers.google.com/" ><img src="./image/google.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.gnu.org"><img src="./image/GnuTuxSoftRevolution-v1.jpg" style="width:580;height:400;"/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<!--end slider------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

to see my code complete code of my app https://github.com/madan-ram/facebook-app/blob/master/index.php.

Comment: Can I have JS FIDDLE version for this?